# Are there any overlaps between the Judo kodokan techniques and Sumo's kimarite?

Tags: judo, technique, sumo

Looking over the [wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimarite), it seems like some of the kakete techniques might be near or even pure analogs of judo throws. Kekaeshi for instance, would be a good candidate. But others involve grabbing the legs/ankles/feet and would be forbidden. The Nagete also seem like good candidates.

What would be the best way to compare these carefully to determine which are identical, which are similar but still significantly different, and which have no analog in the other art? I am moderately familiar with Judo, but unfamiliar with Sumo (don't exactly get NHK on basic cable here, nor do you see honbasho summaries in the sports section of the local paper).

Answer (score 4):

### If you throw, there is a name

Yes, there are overlaps. If you throw someone on their back, judo will have a name for it, and sumo will have a name for it. I imagine the classifiers will force throws into one category or another, even if they are sufficiently distant from the canonical versions that non-experts may not be able to identify them.

As I am more knowledgable of judo, my strategy would be to take sumo techniques and map them to judo ones.

Some examples:

| Sumo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| [ipponzeoi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDsqMQeSUiA) | ippon seoi nage |
| [kakenage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQn06JwLaWc) | uchi mata |
| [koshinage](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/sumo/techniques/72/) | ogoshi, uki goshi, tsuri goshi |
| [kubinage](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/sumo/techniques/60/) | koshi guruma / [kubi nage](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9458/5961) |
| [tsukaminage](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/sumo/techniques/74/) | tsuri goshi |

Judo classified throws while touching the legs was legal, so even if a throw may not be competition-legal now, it will still have a name.

I will not pretend to understand how sumo classifies its techniques, so I can't do the reverse.

### In judo, not in sumo

Sacrifice techniques will generally not be in sumo because of the danger of touching non-foot parts before the opponent lands.

### In sumo, not judo

Anything where you win by pushing out or down without a throwing action.

Answer (score 4):

NHK has video examples of sumo's kimarite [here](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/tv/sumo/techniques/).

## Main differences

In judo the aim of throws is to put the opponent flat on their back, with control and speed. In sumo however, the aim is to have any part of the opponent's body touch the ground / step out of the contest bounds.

As such:

- throws forcing the opponent to fall forwards
- lifting/pushing/slapping/forcing the opponent out of the arena

do not have judo analogues.

On the other hand, the presence of a jacket in judo presents [a greater variety of throwing techniques](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9093/what-is-the-difference-between-judo-and-wrestling/9132#9132) not possible in sumo.

## Shared techniques

#### Kihonwaza (basic techniques)

These are basic sumo techniques, where the main mechanic is forcing your opponent out of the bounds of the ring. These have no analogue in judo.

#### Nagete (throws)

Most of these are also found in judo:

| Sumo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| Ipponzeoi | Ippon-seoi-nage |
| Kakenage | Uchi-mata |
| Koshinage | O-goshi Uki-goshi |
| Kotenage | Ude-hishigi-waki-gatame |
| Kubinage | Koshi-guruma |
| Nichonage | Osoto-gari Osoto-otoshi Ashi-guruma |
| Tsukaminage | Tsuri-goshi |
| Yaguranage | Hane-goshi |

#### Kakete (Leg trips)

Again, most of these have a judo equivalent:

| Sumo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| Ashitori Watashikomi | Kuchiki-taoshi |
| Chongake Mitokorozeme | Kouchi-makikomi |
| Kawazugake | Kawazu-gake |
| Kekaeshi | Kouchi-gari |
| Kirikaeshi | Tani-otoshi (with block) |
| Komatasukui Omata Sotokomata | Sukui-nage |
| Kozumatori Susotori | Kibisu-gaeshi |
| Nimaigeri | Harai-tsuri-komi-ashi |
| Sotogake | Ko-soto-gake |
| Susoharai | Ko-soto-gari |
| Uchigake | O-uchi-gari |

#### Sorite (Backwards body drops)

| Sumo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| Izori Shumoku-zori Tasuki-zori | Kata-guruma |
| Kake-zori | Tani-otoshi |

#### Hinerite (Twists)

Most of these throws involve either forcing the opponent onto their front, or twisting them on their back by means of an armlock. Neither of these have clear judo equivalents.

#### Tokushuwaza  (Special techniques)

Most of these involve lifting/forcing the opponent out of the contest area, or pushing them face forward onto the ground, but a couple are similar to some judo throws:

| Sumo | Judo |
| --- | --- |
| Yobimodoshi | Sumi-otoshi |
| Utchari Tsuriotoshi Okuri-tsuri-otoshi | Ura-nage |

---

**A note on technique categorisation**

Sumo organises throws by their main mechanic (pushing, tripping, throwing etc), whereas judo organises them traditionally by the key body part utilised in the throw (hands, legs, hip, or sacrifice throws).

Sumo throw names were standardised after the Judo syllabus (1935), and has likewise gone under a number of revisions since. Additionally, there is a lot of cross-over in techniques post-WWII when a number of prominent judoka transferred to Sumo (considered a sport) after [martial arts (budo) practice was banned](https://ejmas.com/jcs/jcsart_svinth_1202.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Yes some tehnique  like the uchi mata is the same for judo and sumo.